# Uploading Workflow artifacts to S3 from Github action

Tags: amazon-s3, github-actions, artifacts

Github storage has limited me from storing artifacts so my idea is to host those artifacts on AWS S3. There are two files that I want to save as artifacts in the pipeline. as you see I have two files `test.txt` and `test2.txt`.

```
  - name: Upload artifacts.
    uses: medlypharmacy/s3-artifacts-action@master
    with:
      aws_access_key_id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      aws_secret_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      aws_s3_bucket_name: "my-bucket-s3-hii1"
      source_path: |
        test.txt
        test2.txt
      destination_path: /underfiles/files/
```

so there are two problems:

- When I look at the output of the ci I see that it tries to put something in `s3:..../my_repo/underfiles/files`. What is my repo name doing there?
- How can I have multiple files are artifacts and save them on S3?

Comment: I am also trying to take the artifact from my build and send a file to S3.  This is running on a Windows instance (.net program) and so ubuntu is not an option.

Comment: Hi @DanielWilliams . What do you mean? What different does it make exactly?